# JS-created form elements not submitting

Tags: php, javascript, css, forms

I've got a form, with "regular" form elements, and then also form elements which are created by clicking a javascript button. Here's how it's called:

```
<script src="incld/addClass.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">  
</script>  
<input type="button" value="Add a Class" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');" class="add-class-btn">
```

When I look at the $_POST output, though, these elements haven't been submitted.

Here's the JS:

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 25;
function addInput(divName){
  if (counter == limit)  {
     alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
  } else {
     var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
     newdiv.innerHTML = "Class " + (counter + 1) + "          <p><label for=\"class_name\">Class Name </label><input type=\"text\" name=\"class[" + (counter + 1) + "][name]\" id=\"class[" + (counter + 1) + "][name]\" class=\"text-fld\" /></p><p><label for=\"class_grade_level\">Grade Level </label><input type=\"text\" name=\"class[" + (counter + 1) + "][grade_level]\" id=\"class[" + (counter + 1) + "][grade_level]\" class=\"text-fld\" /></p><p><label for=\"class_subject\">Subject </label><input type=\"text\" name=\"class[" + (counter + 1) + "][subject]\" id=\"class[" + (counter + 1) + "][subject]\" class=\"text-fld\" /></p>";
     document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
     counter++;
  }
}
```

Edit:
The "regular" form elements are in a different div tag than the JS-created ones. Maybe this matters?

Edit2: Full (edited but ugly) source available here: http://pastebin.com/y5QJU4NN

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: Make sure you also check what the HTTP request looks like from the browser, to make sure that the problem is not on the PHP side. The network tools in Chrome's debugger can help, or for Firefox there's the Tamper Data plugin.

Comment: Is the element with id 'dynamicInput' inside the `<form>` element?

Comment: Martin: yes. Pointer: I will. watcher: yes.

Comment: @amindfv: Can you post all of the code concerning your form, also?

Comment: @watcher: http://pastebin.com/y5QJU4NN

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy your code and create a form that submitted without changing it.  However, on the receiving side after the form was submitted, I wound up with a `POST` structure similar to this:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

---

```
array(1) { 
    ["class"]=> array(1) { 
        [2]=> array(3) { 
            ["name"]=> string(5) "test1" 
            ["grade_level"]=> string(5) "test2" 
            ["subject"]=> string(5) "test3" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

---

So it looks like the code you posted above works.  Check to ensure that you are inspecting the right array level in the `POST` in your handler script.

---

**Edit**

It looks like PHP was not liking your use of array indices as field names.  I am sure you can specify a field name such as `class[]` and PHP will capture all incoming fields with field name of `class[]` as an array, but I am not sure you can specify a field name like `class[1][name]`.  I changed the field names in your JS to be something along the lines of:

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"class-" + (counter + 1) + "-name\" 
    id=\"class[" + (counter + 1) + "][name]\" class=\"text-fld\" />
```

And after submitting it was inserted into the POST just fine.  Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Doing a var_dump, I get the data from the other input elements, but not the JS-created ones. Could being in a different div tag matter?

Comment: No.  If something is posted from the form, it should be populated in the POST array.  If it is not in the POST array, then you are not getting the fields into the DOM as children of the form correctly.